# Show group chart in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

How to show the sum of bars of a tick in jqplot. I want to show the values of each month as sum in top of that bar in line as shown to below image.

[image]

Starting fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/bywfc5xx/1/

```
`var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
var s2 = [460, 210, 690, 820];
var s3 = [260, 440, 320, 200];
// Can specify a custom tick Array.
// Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];`
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what are u trying to do, to have the total there use:

```
var total = [s1[0] + s2[0] + s3[0], s1[1] + s2[1] + s3[1], s1[2] + s2[2] + s3[2], s1[3] + s2[3] + s3[3]];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3, total], {..
```

The implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/e4zasp6L/

Ok, got it,here is the updated answer: http://jsfiddle.net/282tkr12/

```
series:[
        {
              label:'Total',
              color: 'blue' ,
              renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
              rendererOptions: { 
                  barWidth:80,
                  shadowAlpha: 0,
                  barPadding: -86,
              }
            },
            {label:'Hotel'},
            {label:'Event Registration'},
            {label:'Airfare'}                
        ]
```

Comment: The blue bar must be sum of its series under that tick

Comment: Can you display that total green in full width of respective tick as in the image

Comment: Great, one more. Is there way to add blue bar on top of this series http://jsfiddle.net/282tkr12/2/

Comment: Thats really cool. BTW, i notice that now bar are aligned towards right. there is space left in left side. I knew this is because of new series. Is there any way we can shift that towards left and make child bars in center of ticks. That will solve this. many thanks

Comment: This is the last replay: http://jsfiddle.net/4f0bvq2y/ or http://jsfiddle.net/gxax7qr1/